# How to center a video

Tags: tinymce, media

I am using tinymce v5. I have enabled the media plugin and configure it to get the following html when a user insert a video:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe src="' + newUrl + '" class="embed-responsive-item" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe</div>';
```

In the editor, I can not find a way to center the video on the page. When "selecting" the video, i clicked on the align center button but nothing happen and nothing is added in the html code. Is there anything special that needs to be done? I would like to get the same thing as when I center an image.

Thx!

Comment: When you say "selecting" the video are you highlighting it (drag and select) or single clicking to get a "focus" border? In my testing selecting via highlighting appears to work as expected. Here is a blank Tiny Fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/baaaab 

Can you reproduce the issue there? If so, please Fork and post the new URL.

Comment: @TinyLincoln Thx for your reply. In your fiddle, the generated code is the standard one produce by the media plugin. I did modified it a little bit to get responsive media. The generated code is then: <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wIZrrrwBZvk" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" data-mce-fragment="1"></iframe></div>. With this, I am not able to "select" it and center it.

Comment: Maybe I'll help someone, there is not a good but working way to center the video in tinymce. Insert the tape above the video and under the video select everything from the top bar to the bottom, and press the center button, the center buttons work. Tapes can be left blank. I understand that you have already found the answer, I leave it for other people.